# How can I re-route Cocoa applications through ssh -X?

Tags: software-recommendation, terminal, ssh, cocoa

Is is possible to re-route Cocoa applications through `ssh -X`? I like being able to route X applications, but I want to route Cocoa applications too. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-do-i-run-a-gui-app-via-ssh)

Comment: @cftarnas Not quite. That is talking about running GUI apps through SSH. I want to run Cocoa apps. That post also refers to X window apps.

Comment: By GUI Apps he meant Cocoa apps (well, possibly Carbon as well), and by SSH he was tunneling them over the X protocol the same as you want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - Cocoa is not an X windows compatible system. The closest you will get is screen sharing (VNC). See this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-do-i-run-a-gui-app-via-ssh) for more info. For Lion like background sharing with 10.5 and 10.6 see this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/9681/remote-background-gui-login-to-osx-workstation) on third party VNC tools.

Comment: Hmm...I saw that question. Is it possible to have Lion-like screen sharing between two Leopard/SL computers?

Comment: Yes - Lion just added the ability to share users that are logged in the background, Apple introduced screen sharing in Leopard (10.5). This [Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/131094/2007/12/screensharepower.html) gives a good intro for 10.5.

Comment: What I meant was Lion-like sharing on older OSes. Without a Lion computer involved.

Comment: With third party tools, see this [question](http://serverfault.com/questions/9681/remote-background-gui-login-to-osx-workstation).

Comment: The second question gave me the answer. Using VineServer works! I can't tell you how excited I am about this! Thank you sooo very much!

Comment: Actually it was a question linked within the second question. See http://serverfault.com/questions/8966/mac-os-x-multi-user-thin-client-server-terminal-server

Comment: You can tunnel that through ssh using the -L flag to ssh to tunnel it (`ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@mac_computer` would tunnel port 5900 from the local computer to 5900 on the remote mac_computer. Port 5900 is the default VNC port. On your local host you would then connect VNC to localhost to see the remote computer. We can move this discussion to chat if you want to discuss it more.

Comment: Nope, don't even need to do that. I'll detail this more in a bit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1306/discussion-between-daviesgeek-and-cftarnas)

Comment: I documented this in [a blog post](http://thegeektechblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/lion-like-screen-sharing-without-lion.html)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting chat to work with my google auth - looking into it now. In answer to your question in the chat, the -L flag to SSH does tunneling. (-X does port tunneling for X windows).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to connect a VNC server and client tunneled through ssh, and view an app remotely that way.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?